# Multiple Docker at scripted Jenkinsfile

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, solr, jenkins-pipeline

I have an problem. I need a jenkinsfile for my jenkins. To test our package, we need a solr and a mysql server. So the point is, that I want to include this to systems, with docker in an scripted pipeline.

At the documentation, there is an option, where the second docker.image is running in sidecar. And the first is providing the execution enviornment. The problem is, that solr or mysql as execution don't have PHP or Ant. So I want to use the host-system as execution enviornment and the two docker as baseline for my test-enviornment.

Did anyone has an idea, how I can get this?

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-multiple-containers This is the link to the documentation for this by jenkins, but I don't find a hint for my problem.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "So I want to use the host-system as execution enviornment and the two docker as baseline for my test-enviornment."

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. Ähm actually we have jenkins installed on a server with linux. On this php is installed. Normaly jenkins will use the server-system (host-system) for running all commands. So if create a pipeline-script and run it, jenkins will use all necessary programms from the server. So far so good. The problem is, that we want to use for mysql and solr a docker, which is included in the pipeline-script. The point is, that i only can create sidecar-containers. But the main-container is then the executive env. But i want to us econtinue the host-system as executive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins does not support multi-container builds out of the box. You can only allocate one container for your job or one per stage. In your case you'd want to start 3 containers at once - one with solr, one with mysql and one with php, where you'd have your PHPUnit tests run. At this point this is unsupported.

Workarounds:

1. You could setup a kubernetes cluster and dynamically provision agents with a pod template which you have configured in Jenkins settings. Then by allocating a node with the template label you've defined you could achieve what you want.
2. Play around with `docker-compose` and manually start your containers from there. Be sure to have a `post { always {} }` stage which destroys the created containers once the build has finished.

Comment: Thank you. I can try out your ideas on wednesday and will write after that again.